# How can i make my json into valid json like 2nd one

Tags: javascript

```
{
"items": 
  "{'Link': 'http://www.indiansalt.com/services/emp_add_form.asp', 'Title': 'Apply Online'},
  {'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/8522948124.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '},
  {'Link': 'http://www.indiansalt.com/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}"
}
```

EXPECTING:

```
{
"items": 
  [{"Link": "http://www.indiansalt.com/services/emp_add_form.asp", "Title": "Apply Online"},
  {"Link": "media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/8522948124.pdf", "Title": "Notification "},
  {"Link": "http://www.indiansalt.com/", "Title": "Official Website"}]
}
```

How can i make my json into valid json like 2nd one.

Comment: The second one is not valid json. I believe that valid json would have an array for the `"items"` field.

Comment: edited please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't valid JSON for a couple reasons, so if that's truly the format you have it in you need to:

1. replace the single-quotes with double-quotes
2. wrap the string value in brackets
3. then parse the value to a JSON value
4. finally, stringify it if you want it in string format in the end

```js
var theValue = {
"items": 
  "{'Link': 'http://www.indiansalt.com/services/emp_add_form.asp', 'Title': 'Apply Online'},{'Link': 'media/pdf/details/all-india-govt-jobs/other-all-india-govt-jobs/8522948124.pdf', 'Title': 'Notification '},{'Link': 'http://www.indiansalt.com/', 'Title': ' Official Website'}"
}

// replace single-quotes w/double-quotes
theValue.items = theValue.items.replace(/'/g, '"');
// wrap in brackets
theValue.items = '[' + theValue.items + ']';
// parse
theValue.items = JSON.parse(theValue.items);

// if desired in string format, stringify
var result = JSON.stringify(theValue, null, 1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: in browser it is ciming like:  

"more_info": "[\n {\n  \"Link\": \"http://opsconline.gov.in/\",\n  \"Title\": \" Apply Online\"\n },\n {\n  \"Link\": \"http://www.opsc.gov.in/Admin/ContAttach/101819.pdf\",\n  \"Title\": \"Notification \"\n },\n {\n  \"Link\": \"http://www.opsc.gov.in/\",\n  \"Title\": \" Official Website\"\n }\n]"